# fluent-ffmpeg audio filter not working, but works on CLI

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to apply filters to audio using `fluent-ffmpeg`. It's mostly working. But when adding certain filters (such as `asubcut` or `treble`) it produces the error below.

It seems like `fluent-ffmpeg` can't find those filters (when I try a bogus filter name, it gives me the exact same error message).

Any idea what's going on?

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

async function test() {
  const command = ffmpeg();
  command.addInput("./tmp/test.mp3");
  command.withAudioFilters(['asubcut=cutoff=35:order=10:level=1']); // Other filters like "equalizer" work just fine.

  const fileOutputPath = "./tmp/mastered.mp3";
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    command
    .on('end', resolve)
    .save(fileOutputPath)
  });
}
test();
```

The CLI version works:
`ffmpeg -i ./tmp/test.mp3 -af 'asubcut=cutoff=35:order=10:level=1' ./tmp/mastered.mp3`

However, the fluent-ffmpeg version produces this error:

```
  node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

      Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error reinitializing filters!
      Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
      Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
      Conversion failed!

          at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/me/project/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182:22)
          at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
          at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
      Emitted 'error' event on FfmpegCommand instance at:
          at emitEnd (/Users/me/project/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:424:16)
          at endCB (/Users/me/project/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:544:13)
          at handleExit (/Users/me/project/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:170:11)
          at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/me/project/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:209:9)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
          at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
```

Comment: Are the FFmpeg versions the same between the two? `asubcut` for example was introduced in v4.4. Some filters add/remove options across versions as well.

Comment: That appears to be the issue. @ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg seems to be outdated, will have to install the new binaries.